# Homepage on custom Wordpress theme w/ permalinks records two weird page hits

Tags: php, wordpress

I have taken over the development of a website and have written a simple page hit recording script that I've placed in the header.php of the theme. It seems to work great except when visiting the base url of the site.  Then, it records two hits, one has the correct url (www.idataresearch.com) but the other one looks like www.idataresearch.com/page/2/.  Both hits have the wrong page title recorded as well. I have a feeling it's something to do with the loop or the way the template loader is working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why it's doing this but I've decided to just filter out those weird extraneous results.  The site seems to be working well otherwise ...